# CSS :not selector to target specific types of input

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style ALL inputs except for specific types.

For example:

```
input,
input:not(type='email') {
    background: red;
}
```

The above doesn't work

So I want all inputs to have a background of red (obviously I don't this is just an example), except for input elements of type email. The type I am trying to target with the `:not` selector could be different.

Can this be acheived? If not, what is the best solution?

If you're curious I am trying to avoid specifying all types of input that I want to target just so the types I don't want targeting don't get that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
input:not([type='email'])
```

Keep in mind though, that by using `input, input:not([type='email'])` you're actually rendering the condition useless since you're specifying a bare `input` as well.

Comment: can multiple types be targetted? e.g. I want all inputs to be red except types email AND number. After some experimenting I discovered it can be done with input:not([type="email"]):not([type="number"]),

Answer (score 5):

You have to do it like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TT8jf/)

```
input:not([type='email']) {
    background: red;
}
```

Because if you dont use the [] your not making a selector. Also this does not support all older browsers

Comment: can multiple types be targetted? e.g. I want all inputs to be red except types email AND number. After some experimenting I discovered it can be done with input:not([type="email"]):not([type="number"]),